Looking at previous message using discord.js
I have a bot and I want to send a message if the content of the last message sent (in the same channel) is not equal to the content of the message I want to send
basically I want to read the previous message and check if it equals to current message and then return, How do I check the previous message?
Thank you!

You can fetch the last two messages in the current channel. So you would get the message that was just sent and the previous one. Next, you compare the contents of these messages; if they're not equal, you can let the bot send a message.
Here is a simple example:
client.on(Events.MessageCreate, async (message: Message) => {
    // Ignore messages from bots
        if (message.author.bot) return;

        // Get the previous message
        const previousMessage = (await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 2 })).last();

        // If there is no previous message, return
        if (!previousMessage) return;

        const match = previousMessage.content.toLowerCase();

        // Check if the message content matches the string
        if (message.content.toLowerCase() === match) return;

        // If the message content does not match the string, return a reply
        message.reply('Contents do no match!');
});

Keep in mind that this example does not have any proper error handling. You would have to add this yourself
